# How to set a Facebook messenger label for a user using javascript in a Facebook bot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, messenger

I have a new Facebook bot developed using the Facebook Bot get started tutorial. Now I need to know how to set a Label for a user in messenger. I went over all the Facebook messenger API but could not find a way to do it. Any ideas how to do that? What about setting label colors? (Similar to what you can do manually in messenger)

Comment: still don't know who this is done. Any answer would help, even "i don't know!"